# Activating a hotspot programmatically on a rooted 7.x device

Tags: android, hotspot, rooted-device

I am struggling with opening hotspot in a rooted android device for days. I am able to create and open hotspot. The code I use to create a Wifi configuration:

```
if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
        }

WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID =  ssid;
conf.preSharedKey = encodedKey;
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);
conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
```

And Opening the hotspot:

```
try {
      WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

      if (enabled) 
      {
         mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
      }
      mWifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

      return (Boolean)  mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class).invoke(mWifiManager, conf, enabled);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Everything works great up to here, but while I am trying to connect to create a hotspot with my iPhone, It shows me **No internet connection** error and connection fails.
As I observed, hotspot is turning on, I can see the hotspot when I search nearby hotspots with my phone.

The main problem here I think the hotspot is not being activated.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I mean hotspot.